# Problem getting the AssemblyVersion into a web page using Razor /MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, assemblies, razor

I'm using the following code in a footer in my _Layout.cshtml file to put the AssemblyInfo version data into the footer of every page in my MVC3 site.  However:

```
@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Just prints in the footer:

```
Revision 0.0.0.0
```

When I modified the view to display all of the assembly info for the "Executing Assembly" using the following

```
@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().ToString()
```

Which prints the following:

```
Revision App_Web__layout.cshtml.639c3968.hlogy75x, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

This shows that the "Executing Assembly" isn't my main app, it's the view itself.

**How do I get the assembly information for the ACTUAL app, not just the individual views??**

Answer (score 228, accepted):

cshtml/vbhtml is dynamic compile to assembly.

```
@typeof(YourApplicationNamespace.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

how about this?

Comment: And `@GetType(YourApplicationNamespace.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName.Version` for all the VB.NETers.  Both of us.

Comment: I must also share my praise - this tops of my "show the revision number in the app for qa" story along with [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] I get a nice looking build number. Works great.

Comment: For WebAPI sites: `@typeof(YourDefaultNamespace.WebApiApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version`.  It may even work without the default namespace: `@typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version`

Comment: `@typeof(YourApplicationNamespace.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(3)` returns 3 of the 4 parts of the assembly version if anyone is curious. You can vary between 0 and 4.

Comment: I love SO just for these types of answers. It might have been answered way back in 2011 but in 2017 it still proves to be a lifesaver!

Comment: in dotnet core 2.1 this works for me: `@{Version version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;}` then `<h1>Ver. @version</h1>`

Answer (score 22):

This works for me. Without needing to explicitly mention the type.

```
@ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version
```

Comment: Works also on quite old .aspx pages

Comment: Dope, works on .NET6 also, used it like: `<p class="w-100">Build date:<br />@(new System.IO.FileInfo(ViewContext.GetType().Assembly.Location).LastWriteTime)</p>`

Answer (score 17):

Using this helper works for me:

```
    public static HtmlString ApplicationVersion(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var version = asm.GetName().Version;
        var product = asm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute;

        if (version != null && product != null)
        {
            return new HtmlString(string.Format("<span>{0} v{1}.{2}.{3} ({4})</span>", product.Product, version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision));
        }
        else
        {
            return new HtmlString("");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to get the assembly of a type in the project:

```
typeof(MyType).Assembly.Whatever
```

Where `MyType` is any type in the MVC project itself (eg, a controller or model, or the `MvcApplication` class)

```
 <p>Assembly Version: @typeof(EdiServer.Controllers.HomeController).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();</p>
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer than the accepted one IMO, since it makes it clear that you're looking for a Type that's part of your application's assembly.  Sort of explains the cause of the problem better.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on takepara's answer, if you want a one liner to get the AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute from a MVC Razor View:

```
@System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(Zeroarc.Candid.Web.MvcApplication).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

for an api controller I used this based of other answers

```
Version = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the GetCallingAssembly(). I'm not sure if that is high enough up the call stack or not, but since Razor actually creates an assembly for each view, it stands to reason that your app would be the calling assembly for the view assembly.

Comment: Get Calling assembly just goes one level up in the tree... still no good.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had renamed the namespace afterwards and I got the error above.
The problem was the old namespace reference in the Views\Web.config . I had to change it from `Project.WebAPI17` to `Company.Project.WebAPI17`

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Company.Project.WebAPI17" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score -1):

GO to Home Controller and just copy this code :

Rename `ActionResult` to String

```
public string Index()

   return typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString() ;

run view
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get it using Name property as below:

```
  @System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

is that what you are looking for?