# System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() always returns 0.0.0.0

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-mvc-4

I have modified my assemblyinfo.cs with this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

and on the _layout.cshtml I put this so I can recognize in which build I am testing:

```
 @System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

it always prints `0.0.0.0`

When I go to the bin folder and check the dll properties, version says 1.0.343.2323 so I dont get it?

Comment: Print out `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()`

Comment: it shows this: App_Web_awsfl1ei, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assembly name shown is of some `runtime assembly loaded by IIS`, instead use `EntryAssembly` if entry point for your application resides in the assembly for which you have updated the AssemblyInfo -

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

In case it's different than the calling assembly you can do this way -

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YourAssembly.AnyClass)).GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: There has be to some entryPoint. Otherwise you can use other method `GetAssembly()` by providing type of your assembly explicitly.

Comment: ok, but when I put the Assembly Name in YourAssembly, it wont even compile  Error 5 'FullStackSampleApplication' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' c:

Comment: You need to provide type of any class of that assembly. See the updated answer.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer. but also found this question here that helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156903/problem-getting-the-assemblyversion-into-a-web-page-using-razor-mvc3?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the executing assembly is not the one you've compiled, but a dynamic assembly created by IIS.

Try using

```
typeof(Your_Type_From_NonWeb_Assembly).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Comment: I dont get it, I tried to put the assembly name there, but it wont compile.    @typeof(FullStackSampleApplication).GetName().Version.ToString()

Comment: typeof expects the name of the class to be put in it. So you can put any class from your assembly there.