# Display version in ASP.NET page footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I was mantaining a ASP.NET project developed on Net Framework version 4.8 (no MVC).

In the footer i whould display the application version

```
<span class="text-primary d-inline-block pe-3 border-end border-secondary"><%=System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version%></span>
```

But it's always zero, and it's not clear to me why of this.
Belwo what i get if i place a breakpoint in the aspx code and check the assembly

[image]

--Edited : added source text from immediate windows

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
{0.0.0.0}
    Build: 0
    Major: 0
    MajorRevision: 0
    Minor: 0
    MinorRevision: 0
    Revision: 0
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()
{App_Web_quu0wl55, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
    CodeBase: "file:///C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/67b011a5/aa7c629d/App_Web_quu0wl55.DLL"
    ContentType: Default
    CultureInfo: {}
    CultureName: ""
    EscapedCodeBase: "file:///C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary%20ASP.NET%20Files/vs/67b011a5/aa7c629d/App_Web_quu0wl55.DLL"
    Flags: PublicKey
    FullName: "App_Web_quu0wl55, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    HashAlgorithm: SHA1
    KeyPair: null
    Name: "App_Web_quu0wl55"
    ProcessorArchitecture: MSIL
    Version: {0.0.0.0}
    VersionCompatibility: SameMachine
```

All the test are made with IIS Express on a local machine (the machine i use to develop code)

Comment: Could you replace that image with its original text? It contains useful information, but plain text is easier to read. Or course still replace private info

Comment: @HansKeﬆing you are right, i have added the information required as text, if something else missing let me know and i will give you all the required infromation. 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992883/system-reflection-assembly-getexecutingassembly-always-returns-0-0-0-0

Comment: @Amit thanks exactly what i am looking for. My apologies for not hanving found it by myself